# JavaScript variable containing line breaks

Tags: javascript

I have text containing line breaks from a TextArea stored in a database. A php script tries to retrieve this text and store it in a JavaScript variable. The problem is that the string is not properly understood by JavaScript and it is interpreted that JavaScript variable is not correctly ending because JavaScript assumes a line break.

Any idea how could I save text containing line breaks in a JavaScript variable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea how could I save text containing line breaks in a JavaScript
>   variable?

Yes, Use [PHP's `json_encode`](http://www.php.net/json_encode):

```
 var myvar = <?php echo json_encode($myVarValue); ?>;
```